# Facebook Login on Firebase registering but authentication doesnt work

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin.android, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I have implemented Facebook Authentication in my xamarin Android app and everything works fine. I get token from facebook and using signin method of firebase rest Api, I am able to sigin to Firebase and receive back an access token which as JWT from the firebase api.
But however when I want to use this access token on my Web Api Core which implements a firebase authentication using code below based on this [article](https://blog.markvincze.com/secure-an-asp-net-core-api-with-firebase/), it always returns not authenticated. 
The same code works for Google Authentication following exact the same steps. It works also for email+password authentication.
What could be the problem with Facebook?

Differences I recognized, when I go to https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/myfirebase/authentication/users

I can see google users, email users but not facebook users. what does that mean? if not registered, why do I get an JWT token from firebase.

Another one is that google has a expiry date, but facebook token doesnt have.

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://securetoken.google.com/my-firebase-project";
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/my-firebase-project",
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = "my-firebase-project",
            ValidateLifetime = true
        };
    });
```

EDIT: I tested with another facebook account and it is actually working. Problem seems to be fb account doesnt work is connected to a gmail account which already registered using google sign in. So Firebase doesnt create another account for Facebook if email connected to is already registered using other Oauth2 method.
But I dont understand why it doesnt allow me to authorize if I can authenticate and get an JWT token from firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Till firebase release official solution to this problem, the work around will be to enable multiple accounts per email address in the **sign-in method** under Authentication

[image]